# 'charmap' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy and get this error when printing tweet messages on the screen (Windows).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json

#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey = 'xyz'
csecret = 'xyz'
atoken = 'xyz'
asecret = 'xyz'


class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print json.loads(data)['text']
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, Listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['#hash1', '#hash2'], languages=['en'])
```

> ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > "C:....twitterSentiment.py",
> > line 34, in <module>
> >     twitterStream.filter(track=['#hash1', '#hash2'], languages=['en'])   File
> > line 430, in filter
> >     self._start(async)   File "C:......streaming.py",
> > line 346, in _start
> >     self._run()   File "C:.....streaming.py",
> > line 286, in _run
> >     raise exception UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 108-111: character maps to <undefined>
> ```

It is caused by Windows not supporting all characters. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: can you post your code here? pastebin

Comment: You need to paste the code the error is referencing, the error just tells us where to look for a mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error, because it is not able to print `unicode` part of `tweet.text`. Encode it to `utf-8` (unicode).

```
def on_data(self, data):
    print json.loads(data)['text'].encode('utf-8')
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chcp 65001
```

This is the prescribed solution in multiple threads. I was using a symbol "∞" which was not getting printed. I ran the python code from cmd after running

```
chcp 65001
```

It worked like a charm. Hope it helps.

> p.s. It only works in cmd not in atom editor nor via cygwin.